# How to update a record from first table through the other two tables?

Tags: mysql

I have three tables:

`TableA`

```
+-------+--------+--------+
| id_a  | name   | total  |
+-------+--------+--------+
|    1  | Andrew |        |
|    2  | Jhon   |        |
+-------+--------+--------+
```

`TableB`

```
+-------+--------+--------+--------+
| id_b  | id_a   | amount | id_c   |
+-------+--------+--------+--------+
|    1  | 1      |    5   | 1      |
|    2  | 1      |    1   | 2      |
+-------+--------+--------+--------+
```

`TableC`

```
+-------+--------+
| id_c  | status |
+-------+--------+
|    1  | 1      |
|    2  | 0      |
+-------+--------+
```

So what I need to do is to count a total sum of amounts from TableB where id_a = (1 or my posted id) AND where status of id_c is 1 or 0 and set it into the TableA in total column, for the data in the tables I've posted above the field `total` in a TableA where id_a = 1 will contains a `6` value.

I'm trying to go in my query through this way:

```
UPDATE TableA SET total=(SELECT SUM(amount) as sum FROM TableB WHERE id_a = 1 GROUP BY(sum))
```

but this is way is wrong ( I think ). How would be nice query to this?

Comment: "So what I need to do" Why?

Comment: help, or I'm asked a hard task? If it's so, I'm very appoligize.

Comment: This is awkward schema design.  Caching simple results is a great way to end up with data out of sync.

Comment: no doubt I can cache, but isn't good to have a one query instead of few?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `INNER JOIN` between TableB and TableC in your inner `SELECT`.

```
UPDATE TableA SET
    total=(
        SELECT SUM(amount) FROM TableB
                           INNER JOIN TableC ON TableB.id_c = TableC.id_c
        WHERE id_a = 1 AND (status = 1 OR status = 0)
        GROUP BY id_a
    )
WHERE id_a = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
   UPDATE TableA SET total=(SELECT SUM(amount)  FROM TableB WHERE id_a = 1)
```